# FirebaseCrashlytics - HTTP request failed

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, crahslytics

Tengo un proyecto añadido en firebase y tiene habilitado **FirebaseCrashlytics**. Mi proyecto tiene una pantalla de carga la cual tras 2 segundos deberia quitarse, y lo hace si el dispositivo no esta conectado ni a los datos ni a ninguna wifi tenga o no internet. En caso contrario se queda más de 10 segundos intentandose conectar a FirebaseCrashlytics. Quisiera saber si hay alguna fomra de hacer que esa tarea sea en segundo plano y no en el main thread como creo que se esta ejecutando. Les dejo el logcat que me da:

```
E/FirebaseCrashlytics: HTTP request failed.
java.io.InterruptedIOException: timeout
    at okhttp3.RealCall.timeoutExit(RealCall.java:107)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:96)
    at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.network.HttpRequest.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics@@17.0.0-beta03:129)
    at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.settings.network.AbstractAppSpiCall.invoke(com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics@@17.0.0-beta03:68)
    at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.settings.network.UpdateAppSpiCall.invoke(com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics@@17.0.0-beta03:21)
    at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.Onboarding.performUpdateApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics@@17.0.0-beta03:217)
    at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.Onboarding.performAutoConfigure(com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics@@17.0.0-beta03:198)
    at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.Onboarding.access$000(com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics@@17.0.0-beta03:40)
    at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.Onboarding$1.then(com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics@@17.0.0-beta03:124)
    at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.Onboarding$1.then(com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics@@17.0.0-beta03:117)
    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzp.run(Unknown Source:2)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.ExecutorUtils$1$1.onRun(com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics@@17.0.0-beta03:60)
    at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics@@17.0.0-beta03:27)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
 Caused by: java.io.IOException: Canceled
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:120)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:254)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:92)
    at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.network.HttpRequest.execute(com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics@@17.0.0-beta03:129) 
    at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.settings.network.AbstractAppSpiCall.invoke(com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics@@17.0.0-beta03:68) 
    at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.settings.network.UpdateAppSpiCall.invoke(com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics@@17.0.0-beta03:21) 
    at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.Onboarding.performUpdateApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics@@17.0.0-beta03:217) 
    at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.Onboarding.performAutoConfigure(com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics@@17.0.0-beta03:198) 
    at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.Onboarding.access$000(com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics@@17.0.0-beta03:40) 
    at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.Onboarding$1.then(com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics@@17.0.0-beta03:124) 
    at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.Onboarding$1.then(com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics@@17.0.0-beta03:117) 
    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzp.run(Unknown Source:2) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
    at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.ExecutorUtils$1$1.onRun(com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics@@17.0.0-beta03:60) 
    at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics@@17.0.0-beta03:27) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

Para estar seguro le quite la pantalla de carga y al entrar directo al **MainActivity** no puedo realizar nada hasta que en el logcat no me salga lo que puse anteriormente. He buscado online por algun problema similar pero al parecer no existe. Si necesitan mas informacion edito la pregunta.